# i have error in jspdf like ERROR TypeError: "t is undefined"

Tags: angular

```
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf'
```

---

template:

```
<button (click)="download()">download </button>
```

---

```
download() {

    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.text(20, 20, 'Hello world!');
    doc.text(20, 30, 'This is client-side Javascript, pumping out a PDF.');
    doc.addPage();
    doc.text(20, 20, 'Do you like that?');

    // Save the PDF
    doc.save('Test.pdf');

}
```

Comment: At what line and character does the error gets triggered? Is your code [verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Please provide much more info if you need help with this. Your question doesn't state what are you trying to do, what happens instead, not even the error (you need to put it in the question body, not just in title.

Comment: click download button i got this type of error